# WSO2 Identity Server. Error when processing request

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

getting the following error accessing a tomcat app that is linked to a WSO2 Identity Server

> TID[-1234] [IS] [2014-02-12 11:43:34,386] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -
>   Error when processing the authentication request!
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.unmarshall(SAMLSSOUtil.java:193)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.validateSPInitSSORequest(SAMLSSOService.java:67)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:236)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:132)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:81)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using SSO web application with WSO2IS. According to the error, It seems to be that SAML Request that is send from the SSO web application is not valid. Could you give some more details about the WSO2IS version and the download location of the web application  that you tried out.
However for more detail,  you can enable debug logs in the SAML compoent by adding following entry in to log4j.prorperties file at /repository/conf

> log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml=DEBUG

Comment: hi, using version 4.6.0 of the WSO2IS, also followed the tutorial here: http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/02/enabling-saml2-sso-for-web-apps.html

will attempt the debug option now thanks

Comment: Web app that you are using little bit old...  If you are using IS 460.. Please go through doc...  there is a sample web app that you can try out http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Configuring+SAML2+SSO

Comment: Tried using that but getting an error saying about an invalid parent POM?

Comment: Yes.. please use this pom file to build..and readme there https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/saml ...  if not you have to build all project.

Comment: thanks, another issue arrised:

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dep
endencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apac
he.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apa
che.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.
apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connecti
on timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and fixed it by unchecking "Enable Signature Validation" and "Enable Assertion Encryption".