# wso2 is 5.0 sp1 : Single logout fails after 15 minutes with session persistance on

Tags: session, wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 is 5.0 sp1. We have set the session persistence to 1 day. Our observation is that when we sent a single logout request to wso2 IS within 15 minutes it works as expected i.e it logs off all the registered SPs. But when we sent a logout request after 15 minutes, it fails to logout saying

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-20 10:54:46,749] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor} -  No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-20 10:54:46,755] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Error when processing the authentication request! {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet}
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Invalid SAML SSO Logout Request
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:287)
```

We feel that even though the session persistence is set to 1 day, wso2 fails to validate the session id.

Any suggestions /workarounds for the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Cijoy

Comment: check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727087/wso2-identity-server-error-when-processing-request

Comment: This link just states to turn debug on. What exactly you are referring to?

Comment: i came across this issue before somehow i fixed.unfortunately i forgot how i fixed. it seems similar may be it could help that's why i shared the link .

Comment: Hi Cijoy, can you share the configuration related to session data persistence in your identity.xml file so I can find the problem.

Comment: Hi,<SessionDataPersist>
   <Enable>true</Enable>
   <RememberMePeriod>30</RememberMePeriod>
   <CleanUp>
    <Enable>true</Enable>
     <Period>5</Period>
     <TimeOut>35</TimeOut>
   </CleanUp>
   <Temporary>false</Temporary>
  </SessionDataPersist>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred to the link http://malithiedirisinghe.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-manage-session-in-wso2-is-500.html

Here it describes of using SessionDataPersist.Only which persists all the cache.

On applying this fix on WSO2 Is 5.0 SP1, things were working as expected. May be in later versions of WSO2 IS it is already fixed and you don't need to apply the same.